# Export default not waiting my function return query. React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want login system. My export default not working Read function. Read function query user_id in AsyncStorage. Please help me :)

app.js

```
var sendTabs = <TabsScreens />
var sendLogin = <LoginScreens />

var Read = readStore = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_id');
    if (value !== null) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}

var Welcome;
Read().then((response) => {
  if (response == 1) {
    Welcome = sendTabs
  } else {
    Welcome = sendLogin;
  }
});

export default () => (Welcome)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define new component to handle this logic:

```
export function WelcomeScreen() {
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useState(null); // null | true | false

    React.useEffect(() => {
        void async function getUserId() {
            const id = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_id');
            setIsLoggedIn(Boolean(id)); // true -> user_id found, false -> no valid user_id found
        }();
    }, []);

    return (userId === null)
        ? <Text>Loading...</Text> // this will show until storage is checked
        : (isLoggedIn) ? <TabsScreens /> : <LoginScreens />; // depending on the value of id from storage you show tabs or login screen
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I understood very well what you said. But I hated this React Native. I try to solve more errors than doing things. 
After doing what I said, I started getting 'Error: Element type is invalid' error.